# loop within loop - detecting end of loop in autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey, nested-loops

Let's say I have a bunch of filenames with the names of fruits in them. I want to auto-rename them based upon a folder full of reference files (dummy txt files which contain the names of fruits, a period, then the name of a dessert).

apple.tart, grape.jelly, kiwi.cake, mango.icecream, banana.pudding, cherry.cobbler, etc

I want to select all the files to be renamed, and drag them onto my script.

1. If a file in the loop already contains a certain combo, such as "cherry.cobbler", I simply want the dummyfile to be discarded, and the file should NOT be renamed "cherry.cobbler.cobbler"
2. If a file in the loop contains the word "kiwi", I want it to be changed so that it contains "kiwi.cake".
3. If a file in the loop contains a fruit not listed, I want a catchall string to be added. So "kumquat" would become "kumquat.nodessert"

It is condition #3 which is causing me trouble. I can't seem to come up with the right syntax to specify when the last dummyfile has been checked.

here's some pseudo code

```
Loop %0%
{
   Path := %A_Index%
    Loop %Path%, 1
    LongPath = %A_LoopFileLongPath%    
    SplitPath LongPath, OutFileName, OutDir, OutExtension, OutNameNoExt, OutDrive


    Loop thru folder of fruit combos
         {
         Stringsplit filenames from fruit-combos folder into %fruit% and %dessert%

         If OutNameNoExt contains %fruit%.%dessert%
             {
             FileDelete fruit.combo dummyfile
             continue; skip to next file to rename
             )

         If OutNameNoExt contains %fruit%
             {
             FileDelete fruit.combo dummyfile
             StringReplace %fruit% with %fruit%.%dessert%
             continue; skip to next file to rename
             )

         If OutNameNoExt not contains fruit.combo AND all dummy files have been checked
             {
             StringReplace %fruit% with %fruit%.nodessert
             )
         }
    ; proceed with next selected file
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

put condition 3 outside the inner loop and it seems to work